# How do I get subversion revision numbers to appear in IntelliJ community edition?

Tags: intellij-idea

At the moment I have subversion successfully working but it shows filenames without any revision numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [no such feature in IDEA](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEABKL-329).

By the way, what's the practical reason of knowing each file revision? There is Changes | Repository view where you can see commit log with revisions, it should be enough in most cases.

You can also annotate current file to see who and in which revision changed each line.

Comment: I feel silly asking this but how do I get to the repository view? I've checked the GUI and the manual but cannot find it

Comment: Please refer to help: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/browsing-changes.html.

Comment: When working with multiple modules, I'd like to see which module is actually from a branch or not: MODULE1 [HEAD/TRUNK - highest revision number] MODULE2 [BRANCH/NAME - highest revision number]

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for the version number for a specific file, you can right click Subversion -> Show History.