# Subversion revision numbers of multiple modules in IntelliJ 13

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

I have a project in IntelliJ 13 Community Edition with multiple modules, using Subversion for version control. I have updated one module to another Subversion revision, the other modules remain at head revision.

```
Module 1: trunk/142    <-- head revision
Module 2: trunk/142    <-- head revision
Module 3: trunk/120    <-- another revision
```

Where can I find the revision numbers of the indiviudal modules? They are not displayed anywhere.

"[How do I get subversion revision numbers to appear in IntelliJ community edition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6728729/how-do-i-get-subversion-revision-numbers-to-appear-in-intellij-community-edition)" does not apply here, because I have modules with different revisions. Revision numbers are not displayed in `Changes | Repository`, nor in `Changes | Subversion Working Copies Information`.

Answer (score 1):

try:
    svn status --show-updates --verbose

or in short

```
svn st -uv
```

you may also like the -q options, to show item under version control.
for more details:

```
svn help status
```

Comment: That works certainly. And IntelliJ itself does not display revision numbers of individual modules? Really?

Comment: I do not know IntelliJ. Maybe its configurable and you can add your prefered options. Maybe it have only limited support for SVN in terms of options, although it claims : I would recommand learning command line interface.
IntelliJ IDEA provides full support of features available in Subversion 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to answer myself. Maybe IntelliJ 13 does not support mixed-revision modules *on purpose*. With Eclipse I was used to switch individual modules because switching there was time-intensive and not trouble-free (at least with my Subversion plugin). I don't have this problem with my current IntelliJ setup.

Actually, a project mixed-revision modules introduces more problems than it helps. Now I **always switch the full project to the target revision, not individual modules**.

Any other thoughts on this?